# How do you indicate certain elements in list of list and vectors based on list characteristics in R

Tags: r, list, boolean

For example

```
testList<-list(list(a=1,b=2,c=3),c(1,2),list(a=1,b=2,c=0))
```

I have a list of either numeric vectors or lists of 3 elements.

I want a boolean indicating list elements where the third element (element c) >0.

If I run

```
sapply(testList,function(x)is.list(x) & x[[3]]>1)
```

I get:

> Error in x[[3]] : subscript out of bounds.

But really the problem is that the `x[[3]]>1` should only be applied to the lists, not the vectors.

The `boolean` needs to be of length `testList`. Any simple way of doing this?

Comment: Your second element have length 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition to solve this.  The `if/else` make sure that the second condition will apply only to `list`.

```
sapply(testList, function(x) if(is.list(x)) x[[3]] >0 else FALSE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

According to `?"if"`

> if returns the value of the expression evaluated, or NULL invisibly if
>   none was (which may happen if there is no else).

This can also be used when there are `NA` values without resorting to additional braces.

```
testList[[3]][[3]] <- NA
sapply(testList, function(x) if(is.list(x)) x[[3]] >0 & !is.na(x[[3]]) else FALSE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `&` to `&&` to avoid vectorized boolean operation:

```
sapply(testList, function(x) is.list(x) && x[[3]] > 0)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

According to `?&&`:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined.

So it says `Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined`, that is, for `&&`, it will only proceed if the first condition is `TRUE` thus avoiding check the validity of the second statement for vector of length of 2, for example:

```
x = c(1, 2)
x[[3]]
# Error in x[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
TRUE && x[[3]]
# Error in x[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
FALSE && x[[3]]
# [1] FALSE             # note here it doesn't check if x[[3]] is valid or not
```

This rule does not apply to `&`, however:

```
TRUE & x[[3]]
# Error in x[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
FALSE & x[[3]]
# Error in x[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Both of them throw an error here.